Thousands of case-different files on Google Drive
I'm trying to use rclone to download my entire 10TB Google Drive to local macos disks. I formatted the local disk as case-insensitive, which I realized, too late, is causing a major issue:
I am getting thousands of Duplicate object found in source - ignoring notices – most of which are because of multiple files which have the same name except for case, e.g., IMG1001.JPG and IMG1001.jpg
dedupe --dedupe-mode=rename does not work, because dedupe is case-sensitive.
Other than listing all 2M files and searching for these instance and writing a script to rename them one by one ... which would take days ... is there any other solution?
Or am I SOL?
